# How To Retrive Facebook Profile Picture Comments using Graph API or FQL

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have tried all query but I can not get **profile picture Id**.

because basic Syntax  of graph API is [here](https://graph.facebook.com/obj_id?fields=comments).

if i get picture_id i can query like this `profile_picture_id?fields=comments` so it will give a all profile picture comments.

please help me how to get Profile picture id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `id` of the **profile picture**-

1. Get all facebook albums of the user by -

   ```
   /me/albums
   ```

   [Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums)
2. Loop through the each object of the above albums and check if -

   ```
   type == 'profile'
   ```

   and get the album id from this object.
3. For this album_id, get the value of object **cover_photo**

   ```
   /<album-id>?fields=cover_photo
   ```

   [Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=ALBUM_ID%3Ffields%3Dcover_photo)

   This value of **cover_photo** is the **id** of profile pic of the user.

Comment: I didn't! :-/ You could have closed it as duplicate.

Comment: I meant, I was writing the exact same answer but you were faster than me :-) Just kidding.

Comment: Ohk. Better luck next time ;-)

Comment: ok thanks for answer now i have 35 picture in profile pictures its show me count=35, I want id of this all profile picture. any idea?

Comment: ok thanks i got it all profile pictures id <album_id>/photos?fields=id, picture

Answer (score 1):

FOR FQL this Work for me -

```
SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner=USER_ID AND type="profile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **FQL**, you can get the current profile picture ID with this one-result query:

```
SELECT cover_object_id FROM album WHERE owner=USER_ID AND type="profile"
```

Comment: FOR FQL this Work for me SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner=USER_ID AND type="profile"